# kubernetes UnexpectedAdmissionError after rollout

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I had a service failing to reply to some HTTP requests, digging it's logs it seemed to be some sort of DNS failure on reaching a `proxy` service

```
'proxy' failed to resolve 'proxy.default.svc.cluster.local' after 2 queries
```

So I could not find anything wrong and tried `kubectl rollout restart deployment/backend`.
Just after that these appeared in the pods list:

```
backend-54769cbb4-xkwf2              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-xlpgf              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h4m
backend-54769cbb4-xmnr5              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-xmq5n              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-xphrw              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-xrmrq              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h1m
backend-54769cbb4-xrmw8              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-xt4ck              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h4m
backend-54769cbb4-xws8r              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-xx6r4              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-xxpfd              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-xzjql              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h4m
backend-54769cbb4-xzzlk              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-z46ms              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-z4sl7              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-z6jpj              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-z6ngq              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-z8w4h              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-z9jqb              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h3m
backend-54769cbb4-zbvqm              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zcfxg              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h3m
backend-54769cbb4-zcvqm              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-zf2f8              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zgnkh              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-zhdr8              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zhx6g              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-zj8f2              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h3m
backend-54769cbb4-zjbwp              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-zjc8g              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h3m
backend-54769cbb4-zjdcp              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h4m
backend-54769cbb4-zkcrb              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-zlpll              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zm2cx              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-zn7mr              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-znjkp              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h3m
backend-54769cbb4-zpnk7              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zrrl7              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zsdsz              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h4m
backend-54769cbb4-ztdx8              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-ztln6              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-ztplg              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-ztzfh              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
backend-54769cbb4-zvb8g              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-zwsr8              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h7m
backend-54769cbb4-zwvxr              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h5m
backend-54769cbb4-zwx6h              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h6m
backend-54769cbb4-zz4bf              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h1m
backend-54769cbb4-zzq6t              0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4h2m
```

(and many more of these)

So I added two more nodes, and now everything seems fine except for this big list of pods in an error state which I don't understand. What is this `UnexpectedAdmissionError`, and what should I do about it?

Note: this is a DigitalOcean cluster

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T12:38:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The following seems important: `kubectl describe one_failed_pod`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                    Age    From                    Message
  ----     ------                    ----   ----                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled                 2m51s  default-scheduler       Successfully assigned default/backend-549f576d5f-xzdv4 to std-16gb-g7mo
  Warning  UnexpectedAdmissionError  2m51s  kubelet, std-16gb-g7mo  Update plugin resources failed due to failed to write checkpoint file "kubelet_internal_checkpoint": write /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/.543592130: no space left on device, which is unexpected.
```

Comment: So I deleted all the pods created but I still have no idea why / how this happened.

Comment: Please provide more information how this issue can be recreated. Cluster configuration and creation.  In addition please provide `kubectl get pods,svc,ep,nodes kubectl describe one_failed_pod kubectl describe node _your_node` Please use `journalctl systemctl status kubelet` to find out more details

Comment: "cluster configuration and creation" - are handled by digital ocean. I will use your commands if it ever happens again though, thanks :D

Comment: @Hanx it did happen again - I can't post everything here as it is over stackoverflow's limit, but I edited the question with what seems relevant information.
Also where should `journalctl systemctl status kubelet` be run?

Comment: Also, there is plenty of disk on the cluster (<10% used)

Comment: could you please provide yaml for the failed pod (is looks like problem with specific volumes)

Comment: @Hanx is that what you are after? https://gist.github.com/nha/51a0f35344847504fe2c1d00847a5ef4

Comment: What commad did you use before ?
Additional commands `kubectl describe pod your_failed_pod | grep "Controlled By"`
`kubectl describe ReplicaSet/ouput_from_thep_reviuos_example` or `kubectl get rs, kubectl describe deployment your_deployment` to see if it was scaled down up?
Additional helpful `kubectl rollout status deployment/your_deployment  kubectl rollout history deployment/your_deployment --revision=Number`.  You can try and use Kubernetes [Node Problem Detector](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/node-problem-detector) to find more information about your nodes.

Comment: Please take a look for Managing [Compute Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) in addition please verify your nodes by `kubectl describe node Your_node` to find out more information about DiskPressure Capacity Allocatable resources (ephemeral-storage) and Allocated resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll take a look and report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, while describing one of the pods with UnexpectedAdmissionError I saw the following:

Update plugin resources failed due to failed to write deviceplugin checkpoint file "kubelet_internal_checkpoint": write /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/.525608957: no space left on device, which is unexpected.

when doing describing node:

OutOfDisk        Unknown   Tue, 30 Jun 2020 14:07:04 -0400   Tue, 30 Jun 2020 14:12:05 -0400   NodeStatusUnknown         Kubelet stopped posting node status.

I resolved this by rebooting node

Answer (score 0):

Because the pod was not even started you can't actually check the logs. However describing the pod provided me with the error. We had some disk/cpu/memory utilization issues with worker5 node.

```
kubectl get pods | grep -i err
kube-system      coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-6l8s8                            0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          10h     <none>        worker5   <none>           <none>
kube-system      coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-kzt9z                            0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          10h     <none>        worker5   <none>           <none>
kube-system      coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-tgkrc                            0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          10h     <none>        worker5   <none>           <none>
```

```
kubectl describe pod -n kube-system coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-kzt9z

Reason:         UnexpectedAdmissionError
Message:        Pod Allocate failed due to failed to write checkpoint file "kubelet_internal_checkpoint": mkdir /var: file exists, which is unexpected
```

First step was **rebooting the node** which **fixed** the issue. The reason was we had restored some backups to the new cluster and restore process caused this issue.

For the pods because they were a part of replica set, they got spawned on other worker nodes. Therefore we deleted the pods.

A quick way to delete a lot of pods, you can use:

```
kubectl get pods -n namespace | grep -i Error | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

To delete all the erroraneous pods in entire cluster

```
kubectl get pods -A | grep -i Error | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

You can use flag -A/--all-namespaces to get pods from all namespaces in the cluster.

However if they are not getting spawned automatically which would be weird, you can run **kubectl replace**

```
kubectl get pod coredns-autoscaler-79599b9dc6-6l8s8 -n kube-system -o yaml | kubectl replace --force -f -
```

For further a verbose read please refer *kubectl replace --help* and the following [blog](https://uthark.github.io/post/2020-09-30-unexpected-admission-error/)